# UPDATE Statement not generating syntax error when using AND instead of COMMA

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I was browsing on MySQL Documentation about the update. [*See UPDATE Syntax*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html). I found out that the syntax is

```
UPDATE [LOW_PRIORITY] [IGNORE] table_reference
    SET col_name1={expr1|DEFAULT} [, col_name2={expr2|DEFAULT}] ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

When I executed this statement

```
UPDATE SampleTB
SET NAME = '123' AND Address = '456'
WHERE ID = 1;
```

[*See Here for SQL Fiddle Demonstration Link*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a8f82/1)

The query executed successfully and the value of `Name` was `0`. I was expecting a syntax error on the query.

Can somebody explain to me why it didn't generate an error? And why was the new value of the column is `zero` and not `123`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SET NAME = '123' AND Address = '456'
```

is parsed to something like:

```
SET NAME = ('123' AND (Address = '456'))
```

which is one comparison and boolean `AND` of a string and boolean operands.

So it takes the current row's `Address` column value, compares it to a `'456'` string and result of the comparison is used as a second operand for `AND` like `'123' AND false`

Comment: ahh so that's how it behaves in `MySQL` because it won't execute in `SQL Server`. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @dara saquin: mysql is very unobvious in its implicit type casts, yes :-)

Comment: hi zerkms. is there anyway that we can prevent MySQL from implicit casting?

Comment: @JW.: I doubt so. At least I don't see any appropriate mode for that: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html