# Why doesn't MySQL throw an error when AND keywords are used in an UPDATE SET

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

The incorrect syntax (first query) does not appear to throw an error in MySQL even though it's clearly wrong. Why is this?

This is the incorrect syntax

```
UPDATE 
    ATable
SET
    AColumn = '' AND
    BColumn = '' AND
    CColumn = ''
WHERE
    IDColumn = '';
```

This is the correct syntax

```
UPDATE 
    ATable
SET
    AColumn = '',
    BColumn = '',
    CColumn = ''
WHERE
    IDColumn = '';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UPDATE Statement not generating syntax error when using AND instead of COMMA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14090431/update-statement-not-generating-syntax-error-when-using-and-instead-of-comma)

this exact question was answered there.

> `SET NAME = '123' AND Address = '456'`
>
> is parsed to something like:
>
> `SET NAME = ('123' AND (Address = '456'))`
>
> which is one comparison and boolean AND of a string and boolean
>   operands.

Comment: It's funny, since I was in the middle of writing an answer here. And the answer you linked to is also given by me 3.5 years ago. +1 anyway :-)

Comment: and a good answer it was too, lol. I was curious about this too and you answered it well.

Comment: Thanks for that, I couldn't find the other question answering it but I guess I was searching for the wrong thing! Very interesting to know.